# How to send array values by mail

Tags: arrays, bash, email

in linux scripting,

is there a way to use mail function to one time send array values??

```
function my_mail_function(){

# send array values
mail array_values_here "mymail@domain.tld" ;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?  And [what are you REALLY trying to do](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can step through an array with just a little bit of bash code.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Here's a simple array...
a=(one two three)

# The brackets encapsulate multiple commands to feed to the stdin of sendmail
(
  echo "To: Mister Target <target@example.com>"
  echo "From: Julio Fong <jf@example.net>"
  echo "Subject: Important message!"
  echo ""
  count=1
  for item in ${a[@]}; do
    printf "Value %d is %s\n" "$count" "$item"
    ((count++))
  done
  echo ""
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -fjf@example.net target@example.com
```

Note that it'll be safer to use `sendmail` directly rather than relying on the availability and configuration of a `mail` or `Mail` command.  Your `sendmail` binary may not be in the same place as mine; if `/usr/sbin/` doesn't work for you, check `/usr/libexec/`.  It'll depend on the distribution of Linux you're running.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to use `mail` is:

```
mail -s "subject here" recipient1 recipient2 ...
```

the command reads the email body from stdin so you can format it how you like and read it in from a pipe or a here-doc or a file or ...

```
function my_mail_function(){
    printf "%s\n" "${array_var[@]}" | mail -s "array values" mymail@domain.tld
}
```